# Clicking a button via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to mimic the clicking of a form submit button using jquery. The button is a form submit button, but clicking the button just updates the page (I'm guessing it runs a script), ,it does not take you to a new page.

My guess was that the submit made an ajax call, so I tried to use:

```
$('#cart-add').ajaxSubmit({url: formAction, type: 'post'});
```

However, I'm not seeing anything happen. Any ideas?

Comment: right, cart-add is the name of the form.

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is when I physically click the button, I see the page update, and that's what I'm trying to mimic in jQuery. The button that I'm clicking is a submit button for the form called cart-add.

Comment: have you tried $('#cart-add').submit()?

Comment: Yes, and that works, but the problem is it takes me to another page. I'm trying to mimic what the button click does, which is submit, and update the page. I see a script tag that has a form inside of it, that looks like it may do what I need. How do I call the script inside of the script tag?

Comment: That's all the code that I have, the page I am looking at is: http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/shirts/supreme-pink-panther-denim-shirt as an example. I am trying to mimic the add to cart button.

Comment: I have a javascript file that gets executed when the page that I sent you loads. I am building a chrome plugin. All that js file has is:                                                                   
if ($('#cart-add').length > 0) {
    var formAction = $('#cart-add').attr("action");
    $('#cart-add').ajaxSubmit({url: formAction, type: 'post'});
    
}

Comment: Please rewrite the question explaining that you are trying to write a Chrome plugin, what it's for and what is not working, giving all the relevant code, and add the tag for chrome extensions. What you have asked is vague to say the least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be after something like this. Since you didn't post any html I can only assume your button has the ID of cart-add and the form you want in question is let's say 'myForm'. This will bind the click of that button and prevent its default action and perform an ajax post of the form's data you have filled out. Hope this helps.

```
$('#cart-add').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $formData = $('#myform').serialize();

     $.ajax({
       url: 'yoururl',
       type: 'POST',
       data: $formData,
       success: function(response) {
       // do stuff. 
       }
     });

});
```

Comment: I see. How can I mimic the clicking?

Comment: Lets say you wanted to trigger the "click" of the cart-add button. You can do $('#cart-add').trigger('click');

Comment: Also remember to assign this binding before the button is clicked. e.g place it in $(document).ready(function() {'code here'});